# Is there a way to rigorously define the geometrical flattening of a curve?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

Compare the curves $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2+1}-1$:
[image]

It seems to be that $g(x)$ seems like $f(x)$, but so as to have been flattened a bit, as if we grabbed it by its two sides and pulled it down onto the x-axis. Is there any way to rigorously define a flattening action in this sense? I'm thinking that surely engineers have to deal with problems related to the malleability of a material under pressure, which would seem to be what is being represented in the comparison of these curves, and so perhaps there could be a way to define this action mathematically.

Comment: your formula for $g(x)$ doesn't seem to be what was graphed (your $g$ is always negative but the functions drawn are $\geq 0$). But usually the concept used is "the order of a zero". Roughly it's like asking how many derivatives of the function vanish at that point. For example, compare the graphs of $f_n(x)=x^n$ near the origin for various values of $n$. As $n$ gets larger, the graph will look more flat.

Comment: Did you mean $g(x)=x^2 \left( \frac{1}{1+x^2}-1 \right)$?

Comment: Forgot a + sign there!

Comment: @peek-a-boo any search term I could use to get there? Is it the order of a zero of a plane curve, in a specific branch of math? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing rigorous. Just your choice.

Similar to the  even function you chose we can choose *any other disturbance function* $f(x),g(x)$  applied to a parabola that vanishes at the the origin with $y \to 1 \text { as } {  x \to \pm \infty}. $  They would all produce same chosen local transient disturbance and same distant offset:

[image]

```
f[x_] = -1/(1 + x^2) + 1
Plot[{x^2, f[x], x^2 - f[x]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, GridLines -> Automatic]
g[x_] = -E^(-x^6) + 1
Plot[{x^2, g[x], x^2 - g[x]}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do disturbance functions have specific properties? Since I'm assuming they can't take any shape in order to produce the same effect. I've never heard of them, do they pertain to a specific branch of math? Thank you!

Comment: There is no standard definition with properties.  Some examples from Elasticity , plate and shell theory in Mechanics of materials can be given using force equilibrium, Hooke's Law etc . If a cause is given then only the effect as deformation or disturbance can be found.  Deflection of a beam,.. a parabolic notch in a solid  cylinder when impressed by a certain radial pressure load.. a cylindrical tube radially squeezed in by radial forces.....Equations of Elastic Foundation are applicable.... Hertzian contact deformation and stress are also examples.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: A soap film drawn between two rings changes shape /radii due to any pressure p , which is related  to radii  as $ (1/R1+1/R2) =  p/T  $ with T surface tension etc.